# Change values for Items in a ControlTemplate Programmatically

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

Recently i learned how to use the VisualStateManager. I was able to create a custom toggle button with point over triggers. im having a problem now with Programmatically changing Textbox text within the template.

Before i was able to change the information like this

```
        {
            await App.MobileService.GetTable<UserProfiles>().ToCollectionAsync();
            userprofileitems = await UserProfilesTable
                .Where(user => user.Email == MyApp.App.LoggedinUseremail)
                .ToCollectionAsync();

            Uri ProfilePhotoUri = new Uri(userprofileitems[0].ProfilePhotoURL, UriKind.Absolute);
            ImageSource imgSource = new BitmapImage(ProfilePhotoUri);

            UserProfilePhoto.ImageSource = imgSource;
            UserFirstName.Text = userprofileitems[0].FirstName;
            UserLastName.Text = userprofileitems[0].LastName;
        }
```

Now i have set the Toggle button with a StaticResource pointing to the style in App.xaml Which naturally stops my Programmatic code from working correctly.

```
        <Style x:Key="UserProfileToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderThemeBrush}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ToggleButtonBorderThemeThickness}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,4,12,5"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="UserBorder1">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF64C800"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="UserBorder3">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF64C800"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="UserBorder4">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#FF64C800"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="UserBorder1">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="UserBorder3">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="UserBorder4">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="UserFirstName">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="UserLastName">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="UserBorder1">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="UserBorder3">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="UserBorder4">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="UserFirstName">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="UserLastName">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="UserBorder1">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="UserBorder3">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="UserBorder4">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="UserFirstName">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="UserLastName">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="CheckedPressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="UserBorder1">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="UserBorder3">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="UserBorder4">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Blue"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="UserFirstName">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="UserLastName">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Border x:Name="UserBorder1" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2,2,0,2" CornerRadius="150,0,0,200" Padding="0" Margin="15,0,0,0"/>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" Background="White" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="150" Height="40" Width="40" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                    <Border x:Name="UserBorder2" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="150" Height="40" Width="40" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <ImageBrush x:Name="UserProfilePhoto" ImageSource="{Binding ProfilePhotoURL}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                                <Border x:Name="UserBorder3" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,2,0,2" MinWidth="120">
                                    <StackPanel>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="UserFirstName" Text="{Binding FirstName}" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        <TextBlock x:Name="UserLastName" Text="{Binding LastName}" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,10"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Border x:Name="UserBorder4" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,2,2,2" CornerRadius="0,150,150,0" Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
                                    <Border x:Name="UserSettingsBorder" BorderBrush="Black" Background="White" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="150" Height="40" Width="40" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="150" Height="40" Width="40" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                        <Border.Background>
                                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/SettingsIcon.png"/>
                                        </Border.Background>
                                    </Border>
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Is there anyway to access and set the information to the Style Programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this one out myself. I learned how to create customcontrols and create one that inherited from the ToggleButton. I was able to create custom dependency properties to bind the Image and Text Stings to.